# Show pdf in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I show a PDF file in my application?
I have the URLs of the files that I need to open in my database, what I need is to show any of those files.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There are plenty of packages for that : https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=pdf